# Добавление чайлдов,  если еще нет парента в БД

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, sql

Допустим, есть таблица в БД "Дом" и связанная с ней "Квартиры" и есть форма, в которую вводится название дома и добавляются по одной квартиры. 
Проблема в том, что еще не нажимая кнопку сейв на форме, нужно выбрать и соответственно сохранить квартиры. Получается, что чайлды добавляются раньше парента. Пакетно сейвить все сразу не вариант.
Как красиво организовать все это?

Выходит, что уже при заходе на страничку нужно создавать пустую запись в таблице "Квартира"?

Comment: В чем проблема сохранять все квартиры в БД разом, а до этого момента держать информацию о них просто на клиенте или в веб-сессии?

Comment: При открытии формы создавайте черновик дома.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как только ввели название Дома, по логике, он создан? Пусть даже без квартир пока.

Почему бы не сделать форму динамической, и сохранять/обновлять запись в таблице «Дом», как только поле с названием дома потеряло фокус. С этого же момента в клиенте (и сессии) уже будет полученный свежий id этого дома и квартиры будут по одной сохраняться с этим id дома.

Answer (score 0):

```
START TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO home
        INSERT INTO apartment
        INSERT INTO apartment
        INSERT INTO apartment
        INSERT INTO apartment
COMMIT
```

Comment: home_id для apartment кто будет подставлять? или это псевдокод "догадайся мол сама"?